# How to extend an object with a key in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`myObj` is an object which contains some parameters

```
myObj:
    {
     person: "John", 
     age: "20"
    };
```

Now, I need to create a new object similar to original object (only slight changes to values), something like

```
newObj:
    {
     person: "John" + GetVal();
     age: "20" + GetVal();
    };
```

I tried something like:

```
var newObj = {};
angular.forEach(myObj,
                    function (value, key) {
                        _.extend(newObj, { key: value + GetVal() });
                    });
```

But this produces something like,

```
newObj:
{
  key: "John" + GetVal();
}
```

But I am expecting an object

```
newObj:
{
  person: "John" + GetVal();
}
```

Notice that `key` is taken as such but instead it should be the `parameter name` of the original object.

Any ideas how to achieve that ?

Comment: Why not just do `newObj.person = "John" + GetVal();`?

Comment: I don't know the exact property name of `myObj`. It could be anything. All I want is a similar object with every property's value modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`. Please try this:

```js
var myObj = {
     person: "John", 
     age: "20"
};
var newObj = {};

angular.forEach(Object.keys(myObj), function (value, key) {
         newObj[value] = myObj[value] + ' someValue';
     });

console.log(newObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did u mean `newObj[key] = myObj[value] + GetVal()` ?

Comment: No, Object.keys returns an array which items are object key names and you want those values so it should be `value`. If you use `key` in such case it will give you array indexes (0, 1 ..)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Understood, tried and worked great :) Bliss...

Comment: Having a doubt. What is the difference between using `_.extend` and simply using `newObj[value] = oldObj[value]`. Both seems to create a new property called `value` if one doesn't exist.

Comment: `_.extend` is 'underscore' library method which shallowly copy all the properties in the source objects over to the destination object (check underscore doc for more details: underscorejs.org/#extend). So it's helpful if you want to make a copy of entire object without modifications. In your case there is no need to use it since you iterate over object properties with `forEach` loop one by one and use them to build new object. You don't need to copy object but to create new object based on another object properties and you don't need any library to add object property in JS :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `key` is treated as a litteral not an expression, you must use `[key]` instead in your solution to make it work.

```js
var myObj = {
  person: 'John',
  age: 20
};

const GetVal = () => 3;

var newObj = {};
angular.forEach(myObj,
    function (value, key) {
        _.extend(newObj, { [key]: value + GetVal() });
    });
console.log(newObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, using _.each (as in _.extend), you can do the following :

```
var new_obj = {};
_.each(obj, (v, k) => new_obj[k] = v + getVal())
```

```js
var obj = {
  person: "John", 
  age: "20"
};

const getVal = () => '_prefix';

var new_obj = {};
_.each(obj, (v, k) => new_obj[k] = v + getVal())

console.log(new_obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did not know that `newObj[key] = val` would create a new property called `key` in `newObj` and then assign a value to it. Now, understood better

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Object.assign()` like this:

```js
var myObj = {
    person: "John", 
    age: "20"
};

function GetVal(val) {
  return val;
}

myObj = Object.assign({}, myObj, {
    person: myObj.person + GetVal(" Lastname"),
    age: myObj.age + GetVal(" years old")
});

console.log(myObj);
```

You should checkout the documentation on Object.assign() over at [MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) An added benefit of this approach is that your data is not mutated. Avoiding data mutation when possible is always a plus.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the property names of `myObj`. It could be anything. So, you cannot hardcode the `person:` and `age` just like you did above.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see in your question where it mentioned dynamic key names. Definitely use Object.keys() to obtain those keys then. On another note, angular.forEach is much less performant than a simple for loop.